# How To Select A Specific text In A TextArea In Swing

Tags: java

so i have written a code that searches for a word in  a textArea. here is the code:

```
else if(str.equals("Find Next"))
{
    if(ta.getText().length()!=0 && t1.getText().length()!=0)
    {
        int n = ta.getText().trim().indexOf(t1.getText().trim());
        ta.select(n,t1.getText().length());
    }
}
```

for reference, ta is the texarea and t1 is the TextField where the user enter word to be searched. my problem is when i write a string something like this - He is a good boy , and search for say , good , then good is not selected but when i search for "He" , he is selected. what i basically want to say is that if i enter the first word of the string in the textField, it is searched and selected but if i enter any other word it does not get Selected. where am i doing wrong?

Comment: so are you looking for a way to search for the first word?

Comment: No i am looking to search for any word in the string

Comment: Sorry brother , i got what i am doing wrong

Comment: sure, good to know. no worries

Comment: I have to give the length of t1.getText() in terms of ta.getText()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the second argument of select needs to be the ending index of the String -- it's not a size, it's a location.  The code you provided works for the beginning of the String because n is zero, so your location and your size happen to be the same.  I think you can solve your problem by changing your last line to:

```
ta.select(n,n + t1.getText().length());
```

In the working case (at the beginning of the String), n = 0 so we've changed nothing.  In the case that isn't working, this extra "n + " moves us to the location we need to finish at.